# How to bind function keys in zsh?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, function-keys

Does anyone know how to bind function keys in zsh? I want to be able to use function keys in programs running in my terminal, not bind them to some function in zsh. I've tried putting bindkey "\e[OP" key_f1 in .zshrc but I get No such widget `key_f1' when I try that. Suggestions?

Comment: I doubt, that `zsh` is to blame (see my answer), so perhaps you should include in your question, what terminal you use and what program isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

To explicitly assign a key to itself use

```
bindkey "\e[OP" self-insert
```

To unbound a key, use

```
bindkey -r "\e[OP"
```

To get the symbols for a specific key you can simply use `cat`: So `cat` <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> produces in my terminal (URxVT) the following string: `^[OP`. This can vary depending on the terminal, especially for combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

But concerning your specific problem: I doubt, that `zsh` is the reason that the functions key do not work in your program, because when the program is running, `zsh` should not capture any keys. I think it's more probably, that the program itself does not understand the symbols the *terminal* sends to it. So, you could try another terminal (`xterm` worked in most such cases for me). If that failes to, you probably have to check the keyboard mapping of the *X server* (`~/.Xmodmap` in Linux, I unfortunately don't where to tune OSX...)

Answer (score 2):

I have been experimenting with assigning Function keys F1-F12 and found a way:-
In zsh use the following commands in your .zshrc file : bindkey -s '\eOP' ' clear\n' ajust the second part of your command u wish to assign. The key codes can be found online.

For bash use this method: bind '"\eOQ": " clear\n"'
place into your .bashrc file for permanent use.

The keys F1, F10 & F11 are usually assinged already by the terminal you are using and simply goto the keyboard shortcuts menu and reassgin or cancel them.

The key sequence for F1=\eOP F2=\eOQ  F3=\eOR F4=\eOS F5=\e[15~ F6=\e[17~ F7=\e[18~ F8=\e[19~ F9=\e[20~ F10=\e[21~ F12=\e[24~
They should work in most terminals if not user read command or C-v and press key to check key sequence or google.